# Autofixture's AutoData attribute in .net core xunit test projects

Tags: .net-core, xunit, autofixture

Can I use `AutoData` in .net core 2.2 xunit test projects?
`AutoFixture.Xunit` targets .NET Framework 4.5.2 and I can't use it. Maybe there is other NuGet package for .net core?

Comment: `AutoData` attribute works in .net core 2.2. Are you using `Theory` attribute instead of `Fact`?

Comment: I can't add `AutoFixture.Nuget` package to test project because it targets .NET Framework and Xunit test project targets .net core 2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the *AutoFixture.Xunit* [package on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit/), you may notice the following:

> By leveraging the data theory feature of xUnit.net, this extension turns AutoFixture into a declarative framework for writing unit tests. In many ways it becomes a unit testing DSL (Domain Specific Language). **For xUnit.net 2, please use the AutoFixture.Xunit2 NuGet Package.**

(My emphasis.)

Furthermore, if you expand the *Dependencies* section, you'll notice that the package's dependency constraints:

```
AutoFixture (>= 4.6.0)
xunit (>= 1.8.0.1549 && < 2.0.0)
xunit.extensions (>= 1.8.0.1549 && < 2.0.0)
```

Notice, particularly, that the constraint on *xunit* is `< 2.0.0`. In other words, it only works for xunit 1.8.0.1549 up to 1.9.2 (which I believe is the most recent version less that 2.0).

If you want to use xUnit.net 2.0 or higher, you should, as the documentation states, use the *AutoFixture.Xunit2* package. More recent versions also support .NET Core.